# The empty function seems to clear some classes from my wrapper, but not all. Trying to figure out whats wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to create an etch-a-sketch program, and I have got everything sorted, propogating a grid, clearing, and re-creating the grid.  The problem is that the number of columns that the user inputs, seems to be "saved" as a class, and the width of the grid grows in size.  Its making my head hurt, this problem, becaue the number of rows seems to be unaffected (the number of rows is what the user actually inputs).

Im using the $("#wrapper").empty(), but that function does not seem to actually clear everything out in the html.

Here is my JavaScript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/*JQuery variable*/

var $row = $("<div />", {class: 'row'});
var $box = $("<div />", {class: 'box'});
var $solid = $("<div />", {class: 'solid'});

/* Function for creating a grid given two attributes */

var gridCreate = function(input1, input2){
    var rows    = input1;
    var columns = input2;

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        $row.append($box.clone());
    };

    for(i = 0; i < columns; i++){
        $('#wrapper').append($row.clone());
    };

    $('.box').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass('solid');
    });
};  

/* Initial grid with 16x16 */
gridCreate(16, 16);

/*Clear function*/
var clearGrid = function () {
    $("#wrapper").empty();
};  

/* The new grid function, propogated by a prompt
is not working BUGG. Possibly the system is storing the number of rows inputed from a previous grid */
var newGrid = function(){
    var input1 = prompt('How many rows would you like to have (2-20)?');
    var input2 = prompt('How many columns would you like?');
    gridCreate(input1, input2);
}

/***********************Event handler*************************/

$('#clear').on('click', function(){
    clearGrid();
    newGrid();

});
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/easstyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="easscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Andrew's Etch</h1>
    <button id = "clear">Click here to reset</button>

<div id = "wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: `The problem is that the number of columns that the user inputs, seems to be "saved" as a class` What???

Comment: Yes, every time the user propagates a new grid, say with 10 squares width and length, the 10 rows are made. The problem is 10 columns are added to the original 16 that were there.  So instead of the new grid being 10x10, the new grid is 10x26.

Comment: Ok so see answer below, or empty the `$row` too

Comment: Tried that, but it still did not seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to clone `$row` then append the cloned `$box`. As you existing implementation box's added on page load were persisted thus to get rid of that you need to use `$row.clone()` before appending the boxes.

```
var _row = $row.clone();
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  _row.append($box.clone().text('Box ' + i)); //I have used text just for testing
};

for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
  $('#wrapper').append(_row);
};
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*JQuery variable*/

  var $row = $("<div />", {
    class: 'row'
  });
  var $box = $("<div />", {
    class: 'box'
  });
  var $solid = $("<div />", {
    class: 'solid'
  });

  /* Function for creating a grid given two attributes */

  var gridCreate = function(input1, input2) {
    var rows = input1;
    var columns = input2;
    var _row = $row.clone();
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      _row.append($box.clone().text('Box ' + i));
    };

    for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
      $('#wrapper').append(_row);
    };

    $('.box').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).addClass('solid');
    });
  };

  /* Initial grid with 16x16 */
  gridCreate(16, 16);

  /*Clear function*/
  var clearGrid = function() {
    $("#wrapper").empty();
  };

  /* The new grid function, propogated by a prompt
  is not working BUGG. Possibly the system is storing the number of rows inputed from a previous grid */
  var newGrid = function() {
    var input1 = prompt('How many rows would you like to have (2-20)?');
    var input2 = prompt('How many columns would you like?');
    gridCreate(input1, input2);
  }

  /***********************Event handler*************************/

  $('#clear').on('click', function() {
    clearGrid();
    newGrid();

  });
});
```

```css
.solid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Andrew's Etch</h1>
<button id="clear">Click here to reset</button>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: This worked for the most part. I had to add    $('#wrapper').append(_row.clone()).  If I may ask, why did the row.clone need to occur before the box.clone in order for the grid to be propagated properly?